# What is responsible for generating the default constructor?

Tags: java

If every class has a **default constructor** then who generates it, the compiler or the JVM?

Comment: The compiler generates default constructors, but only in classes with no explicit constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Java compiler.

If you don’t implement any constructor in your class, the Java compiler inserts default constructor into your code.

Of course both are same in result and you will not see the default constructor in your source code(the .java file).

And also my teacher told me it is better to add the constructor your self in your source code, even when you have no arguments!

Comment: "And also my teacher told me it is better to add the constructor your self in your source code, even when you have no arguments!" The only reason I can think to do so would be to restrict the visibility of the default constructor. Doing it "just because" is pointless.

Comment: Sure, and also he told me it is a little bit faster because when you do not write it, the compiler has to do, so it will be take a very very little time. But i do not know is this right or not

Comment: "But i do not know is this right or not" I posit that it will take you longer to write the explicit constructor than all the compilation time you could ever hope to save by doing this.

Comment: I would also suggest that you **not** insert an empty default constructor "just because." Write the code you actually need, not the code you think  you need. Another reason to not write an empty constructor is that it allows the compiler to alert you to potential bugs down the road.

Comment: Yes I agree with @AndyTurner here, a massive over optimisation if for performance reasons! Otherwise they could be trying to force you to be explicit, but it just adds unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is that the compiler will generate a default constructor if necessary.

It is definitely the Java to bytecode compiler that does it.  You can confirm this by examining an appropriate `.class` file using `javap`.  You should see the constructor that has been inserted.

However I also want to correct this possible misconception:

> If every class has a *default constructor* ...

In fact, every class does NOT have a *default* constructor.

A *default* constructor is ONLY injected into a class if the class has NO declared constructors whatsoever.  If the source code declares any constructor at all, a default constructor is not injected.  For example:

```
/* This has a no-args constructor, but it is not a "default" constructor */
public class Foo {
   public Foo() {}
}

/* This has no no-args constructor and no "default" constructor */
public class Bar {
   public Bar(int arg) {}
}

/* This has a "default" constructor */
public class Baz {
}
```

(A default constructor is a no-args constructor, but an *explicitly declared* no-args constructor is not a default constructor.  And not all classes have a no-args constructor anyway.)

(At the JVM level, it is a requirement for a `.class` file to define at least one constructor.  However there is no specific constraint on the constructor's argument count and types, or on the constructor's access modifiers.)

---

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66717501/139985) includes a recommendation to explicitly declare no-args constructors rather than relying on Java to insert the default one (see above).

I think this is bad idea:

1. It has zero impact on runtime performance.
2. It has minimal impact<sup>1</sup> on compilation times.  And indeed, it might even make compilation a bit *slower*.

   - If there is no constructor, the compiler notices this, and injects and code generates a default constructor.
   - If there is an explicit (empty) no-args constructor, the compiler must read, parse and typecheck the constructor, and then code generate an identical constructor to the first case.
3. The readability benefit is doubtful.

The only (IMO) *sound* reasons to choose an explicit no-args constructor over a default constructor are:

- because there are other constructors (which means that there WON'T be a default no-args constructor!),
- because you want to restrict visibility of the constructor; e.g. declaring it `private` in a singleton class, or
- because you want to say something (meaningful) in the javadocs for the no-args constructor.

---

<sup>1 - My guess would be a few microseconds.  Too small to make a noticeable difference.</sup>